# Need data on disk drive management by OS: getting base I/O unit size, “sync” option, Direct Memory Access

Tags: database, settings, io, disk

I want to ensure I have done all I can to configure a system's disks for serious database use. The three areas I know of (any others?) to be concerned about are:

1. I/O size: the database engine and disk's native size should either match, or the database's native I/O size should be a multiple of the disk's native I/O size.
2. Disks that are capable of Direct Memory Access (eg. IDE) should be configured for it.
3. When a disk says it has written data persistently, it must be so! No keeping it in cache and lying about it.

I have been looking for information on how to ensure these are so for CENTOS and Ubuntu, but can't seem to find anything at all!

I want to be able to check these things and change them if needed.

Any and all input appreciated.

PLEASE NOTE: The actual hardware involved is VERY modest. The point is to get the most out of what hardware we do have, even though it's "not very serious hardware" from a broader perspective.

MORE:

I appreciate the time taken to read and reply, but I'm hoping to get "answers" that aren't just good database / hardware advice but answers that actually address the specific things I asked about. Namely:

1) What's a good easy way to tell what the I/O unit size is that the OS wants to do? How can I change it? (IOW: If this exclusively a file-system-format issue, how can I tell what was used on an already-created file system? I know /etc/fstab will tell me the file system format... In this case, it's ext3.

2) How can I tell if a disk drive has DMA? If so, how can I turn it on? (I've been told that some drives have this capability, but now I want to follow up and ensure that *if* these drives have it, it's turned on.)

And, finally;

3) How can I tell if a drive is merely telling the writer that their material is written when it's actually still in cache? And, more importantly, how can I set the system to NOT use such features if / when they exist?

Thank you for your insights.
RT

Comment: It helps to know the database you are using, (and also which filesystem you are considering) as each has its own capabilities and options.

Comment: Hi MrJoltCola, I frankly don't see _any_ link between what RDBMS is benig used and the questions I've asked, however, it's Postgres. It has the default 8K page size. (To change it, you must re-compile it.) Thanks for your insights

Comment: There is a big link if you want specific insight. Not sure why you seem defensive about my asking. Since you haven't found my answer useful, I'll refrain from further comment.

Comment: MrJoltCola, I'm not one to either intentionally offend or pass on good insights, so please, don't refrain. ...OK, unlike most, Informix can use raw disk partitions, so I suppose if I were interested in Informix, that could be useful... The file system(s) in this case are all ext3. The reason I responded the way I did is because for some reason I sometimes seem to get a whole lot of response that is _not_ pertinent to what I had asked for - my apologies for having offended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check /sys/block/sdX/queue/{max_hw_sectors_kb,max_sectors_kb}. The first is that max transfer size the hw allows, the other is the current maximum which can be set to any value <= max_hw_sectors_kb

2) hdparm -i /dev/sdX

3) Turn off write-back caching (hdparm can do it), or make sure that the filesystem issues barriers when synchronizing (as in fsync(), or journal commit).

Answer (score 1):

"serious database use" and you mention IDE in the same sentence?

SSDs or 15k SCSI in a many spindle RAID 1+0 array with separate arrays for data, log and backup. Consider a separate array for tempdb too.

You'd also switch the controller cache to 100% read too to avoid caching issues

Of course, if it's "serious" then you'd consider clustering etc: so a SAN comes in useful here but you may not be as quick as local spindles

Comment: +1, yes, I've never had any good come of using write-back cache.

Comment: Hey, don't laugh! (OK, laugh away! -smile- ) This is for a customer who sells a solution including a really cheap set of hardware that the solution comes pre-installed on... No, I have nothing to do with the choices!

Comment: BTW, "serious" meaning not that this is for a big data center, serious as in we need to get as much out of what hardware we do have.

Comment: I sympathise... back in my 100% DBA days I've seen vendors sell large systems with "minimum RAID 5" and had to argue the toss with an analyst or a business person...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any info on filesystem or database, so here are some misc pointers.

It is inevitable that you will lose a disk eventually, so its equally important to put a good backup and recovery strategy in place, and mirror your transaction logs, so you can handle a disk failure or even full datafile loss.

1) If possible, put at least one copy of your transaction log on a fixed disk. Don't put your sole transaction log to an external storage subsystem. (Assuming you use a db that supports log mirroring).

2) I agree with gbn, in practice, don't use write caching. I've lost databases on RAID arrays with battery backup. Configure the storage controller card for write-through.

3) Raw devices provide guaranteed writes, but its not worth the hassle. Some filesystems provide synchronous write options too, use one if possible. I am partial to VxFS, but I'm from the Sun world. On Linux, btrfs is eminent at least, but for now, Ext3 works fine if you setup your db properly.

Comment: Do I gather correctly that merely using the sync option in fstab is sufficient? Somehow I doubt it! I mean; if the hardware has this cache, lie when writes complete feature, it may not honor the OS' wishes regarding sync... To clarify; are there OS / kernel level features that are used to tell drives what to do in such regards?

Comment: When I said sync, I meant the filesystem supports it, and the user process (the database) can open its datafiles in synchronous mode.